# How to check if location which I got with GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER younger than 60 seconds ?

Tags: android, gps, android-location

How to check if location which I got with GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER younger than 60 seconds ? I know to get location.getTime() in ms but I cannot compare that with System.currentTimeMillis() because different timezones. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: @ user370305 To use getLastKnown only if I got that result in last 60 seconds.

Comment: According to Android docs, [Location.getTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime()) and [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) both return ms since since 1 jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC, so you can compare them

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented this and my approach was to copy the `System.currentTimeMillis()` into some `double` variable in the `onLocationChanged()` method of `LocationListener`. that way you get the time exactly when you get a new location. Moreover, you can compare this variable to the same `System.currentTimeMillis()` whenever you need to do so.

i know it's been a while this question is posted but, hoping it might help someone searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

The Location class has include the method getTime(), you can get this value and compare whether it is younger than 60s.
I think it will work for you.